# combine hover and focus selectors styles but not simultaniously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `ul` with list items that are highlighted when they are hovered over or focused upon. However if there is one being hovered and another being focused, then I only want the hovered `li` to change style and the focused elements style to go back to default. Is this possible? Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvy50rbc/3/). Thank you.

**css**

```
li:hover,li:focus{
    background-color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer; 
}
```

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li> 
</ul>
```

**js**

```
$('li').attr('tabindex','0').focus();
```

Comment: Since you have tagged JavaScript and jQuery, I assume you are not looking for a pure CSS solution. Is that a valid assumption?

Comment: Remove li:focus within the CSS?

Comment: @Harry does not have to be pure css, but if possible, then that would be good.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the code you have, do this ...

```
li:focus{
    background-color:yellow;
    cursor:pointer;
    outline: none;
}

ul:hover > li:focus {
    background: none;
    cursor: default;
}

ul:hover > li:hover {
    background: yellow;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

What's the CSS saying?

- Set any list item that has :focus to have yellow background.
- When you hover over the parent UL, set all the li's to have no background.
- When you hover over an individual LI, set the background to yellow.
- When you hover out of the UL, the styling resets.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erier/hvy50rbc/6/)

Comment: brilliant CSS solution. Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: The explanation of what it is doing makes the answer even better. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

Place your :hover CSS class before :focus...

```
.textbox:hover
{
    border-color: lightskyblue;
}

.textbox:focus
{
    border-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can use [blur() event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```js
$('li').attr('tabindex', '0').focus()

$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).siblings('li').blur();
})
```

```css
li:hover,
li:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hover over one and two and three should not be yellow anymore</p>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use only the focus style and add a mouseover event on list items to make them focus when hovering. That way, even if you take the mouse out of the list item, it will remain focused.

```
$('li').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).focus();
});
```